# How to get a string from the last iteration from for-loop in JAVA?

Tags: java, loops

How can i get a string from the last iteration in this loop?

```
    public void Flip()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfFlips; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println("Flip " + i + ": " + headOrTail);
            i++;
            System.out.println("Flip " + i + ": " + headOrTail2);
        }

    }
```

Output for numberOfFlips = 2 is:

Flip 1: Head

Flip 2: Tail

and so on.

My purpose is to get "headOrTail" from the last iteration result and be able to do something with it. Any hints or solutions how to reach it?

Comment: Just assign it to a variable in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is already able to get the result for the last flip. Since you declared variable `headOrTail` outside the scope of the loop, you just have to update every flip and you can print it after the loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfFlips; i++ )
{
    headOrTail = newFlip();    //update your new flip
    System.out.println("Flip " + i + ": " + headOrTail);
}

System.out.println("My last flip: " + headOrTail );
```

---

**Note:** Your current code will always print the same flip results since you are not updating `headOrTail`.

> how to propely create newFlip() method to use it your way?

Depending on the data type of your "flip". If you use integer to represent a flip (for example, 0 for head, 1 for tail), create a method to return a random number of 0-1.

```
//One of the possibilities..
public static int newFlip(){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return rnd.nextInt(2);    //you can use Math.random() as well
}
```

If everything is contained within a class, you can do it as:

```
//Example..
class CoinTosser
{
    private static Random rnd = new Random();
    private int currentFlip;  //this is also your last flip

    public void newFlip(){
        currentFlip = rnd.nextInt(2);  //in this case, no need to return toss result
    }

    public void flipCoin(int times){
        for(int i=0, i<times; i++){
            newFlip();
            System.out.println("Attemp "+ (i+1) + ":" + currentFlip==0?"Head":"Tail");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to propely create newFlip() method to use it your way?

Answer (score 1):

Just ask if it is the las loop.

```
public void Flip()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfFlips; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println("Flip " + i + ": " + headOrTail);
            i++;
            System.out.println("Flip " + i + ": " + headOrTail2);
            if(i==numberOfFlips){
                <do what you want here>
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I actually think this might be more efficient than clobbering a string at each iteration and letting the last assignment fall through outside the loop +1.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a `String`, or a `boolean`, before the loop, and then overwrite it each loop and the last result will be kept in it. Or just save it with a `if` statement checking if it's the last loop as someone suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public void Flip()
{
    String lastInteraction = null;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfFlips; i++ )
    {
        System.out.println("Flip " + i + ": " + (lastInteraction = ((i % 2) == 0 ? "Head" : "Tail"));
        if(lastInteraction.equals("Head")) {
            System.out.println("Last flip was head");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Last flip was tail");
        }
    }

}
```

This will store & print the last result; either Head or Tail

Comment: If i set numberOfFlips to 3 i want only 3rd result. If 2 I want the 2nd result, this code prints out after each result. :D

Comment: Move it outside of the loop then?

Comment: Could you help me with 1 more thing? When i set numberOfFlips to an odd value it prints an even amount of flips (value i wrote + 1), how can i set this loop to work normally?

Comment: change for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfFlips; i++ ) to for (int i = 1; i < numberOfFlips; i++ )

Comment: start the loop at 0 not 1, I used your code to show how it works you got to adjust and think yourself...